# Magento 2 - Checkout Agreements checked by default

Tags: magento2, checkout, terms-and-conditions

I activate the terms and conditions for default onepage checkout on Magento 2.

I want that for default the agreements be checked.

I tried to modify these line on `vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html`:

```
<input type="checkbox"
                        data-bind="attr: {
                                    'id': 'agreement_' + agreementId,
                                    'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                                    'value': agreementId
                                    }"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        checked="checked"
                        />
```

Adding checked="checked".

But i think that as it is a js, it do not marked as checked.

Any idea?

Comment: How to enable this for a single website store ,while we use in multiwebsite store. can anyone help .? in magento 2.2 version

Answer (score 5):

First remove **checkout-agreements.html** from

> pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template

Then add '**checked': 'checked'** in data-bind attributes

```
<input type="checkbox"
    data-bind="attr: {
                'id': 'agreement_' + agreementId,
                'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                'value': agreementId,
                'checked': 'checked',
                }"
    data-validate="{required:true}"
 />
```

Then clear cache and try

Comment: @Albert - El Corriol Please check and let me know if not working

Comment: @Albert This is a correct answer. Its solved my same  problem.

Comment: I apply your code. But, I want more. I want to apply if terms and condition checkbox not checked then error validation display when click on place order. Can you please tell me how to do it.?

Comment: thanx ..upvoted +1

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have remove old file in pub/static

```
<input type="checkbox"
                        data-bind="attr: {
                                    'id': 'agreement_' + agreementId,
                                    'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                                    'value': agreementId,
                                    'checked': 'checked',
                                    }"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"

                        />
```

run command to deploy new content **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: Finally it works!!Thank you!! I remove all files on /pub/static/ and recreate the static files.

Comment: thanx ..upvoted +1 –